# Excel VBA - Copying all but x rows of a table to the bottom of another table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently writing a macro for a piece of work where I need to cut and paste all but x rows (x being defined in cell M2) of a table onto the bottom of a second table. There is also a third table under this which sums values from the two top tables. Afterwards the second table is sorted from Z-A by the number of leads.

Currently I have got to this stage which works if x=1 (If M2 is replaced by 1 it works). However, I want to be able to define how many rows I want to keep in the first table. At the moment when X>1 the papers copied from table 1 end up overlapping the third table which causes problems with the rest of the macro which follows (This is all working correctly and why there is no End Sub at the end).

My tables consist of 7 columns and have no spaces in between them.

```
Sub Complete_Email_Macro()
' Setting Both Partner Report Tab and Final Data as a Worksheet
Dim PR As Worksheet
Set PR = Worksheets("Partner Report")
Dim FL As Worksheet
Set FL = Worksheets("Final Data")

Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = PR.ListObjects("np_last")
tbl.ListRows.Add
Set tbl2 = PR.ListObjects("pp_last")

'Copying papers not needed in pp_last to np_last
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = tbl.Range.Rows.Count
With tbl2.DataBodyRange
    .Offset(M2, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - M2, .Columns.Count).Rows.Cut Destination:=tbl.Range(LastRow, "A").Offset(-1)
End With

' Sort_Table Macro - Sort non-promoted section of the table from greatest no. of leads this month to smallest

    Worksheets("Partner Report").Activate
    Range("np_last[#All]").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Partner Report").ListObjects("np_last").Sort. _
        SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Partner Report").ListObjects("np_last").Sort. _
        SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("np_last[[#Headers],[#Data],[Leads]]"), SortOn:= _
        xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
     With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Partner Report").ListObjects("np_last").Sort
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .Apply
        End With
```

Any help would be appreciated. The issue occurs at the line starting with the offset statement.

Comment: Single-step through the problematic section. 
Use Debug.Print ... 
Etc ...

Comment: In the line where you are resizing the Table, where are you getting "M2" from?  Is this supposed to be a cell reference?

Comment: Hi Frank, Sorry that's my mistake I mis-quoted at the top of the paragraph. M2 is a cell reference, correct (I have now edited this mistake). This will contain a value from 1-5, the number corresponding to how many rows I would like to remain in the first table.

Answer (score 0):

VBA doesn't recognize `M2` as a cell reference. Valid references are `cells(2,13)` or `range("m2")` or even `[m2]`, but it should be noted that even after referencing these cells, each one has properties behind it, like `range("m2").value` or `range("m2").characters`

Comment: Thank you for the help, I've now changed the cell reference to range("m4").value as below

    With tbl2.DataBodyRange
    .Offset(Range("m4").Value, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count.Range("m4").Value, .Columns.Count).Rows.Cut Destination:=tbl.Range(LastRow, "A").Offset(-1)
End With


It is now coming up with a run-time error '424': Object required. Is this because I haven't defined something correctly? Apologies, I've tried to format correctly with Ctrl + K but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: I can't tell which sheet M4 is on, and I don't think the script can either. I would dim the value as an integer up near the top with something like `dim rn as integer` then `rn = worksheets("Sheet3").range("m4").value`. Then you can use the less cumbersome `rn` as variable throughout and not have to worry about the `with` block and such.